# ERC20, correct way of setting totalSupply

Tags: solidity, ether, evm

whats the correct way of setting the totalSupply and why?

```
decimals = 18;
totalSupply = 10000
```

or

```
decimals = 18;
totalSupply = 10000 * (10 ** uint256(decimals));
```

Whats the correct way? What's the difference?
What is (10 ** uint256(decimals)) actually doing?

Seems like the last option is the correct one, because if I dont use the second option, my tokens in Metamask connected to Ganache will show always 0 balance.

Also

```
10000 === 10000 * (10 ** uint256(decimals)) ?
```

---

Also another question, how can I call the methods transfer or transferFrom with a decimal value, sending 2.5 tokens for example? How would that be done, since the type is uint and I cant pass decimals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second way is correct. In Solidity, `**` is the exponentiation operator, so 10 ** 18 is the same as 10<sup>18</sup>. So this:

```
uint256 totalSupply = 10000 * (10 ** uint256(decimals));
```

Means the total supply will be 10,000 × 10<sup>18</sup> tokens. We use 10<sup>n</sup> because Solidity doesn´t (fully) support decimal numbers, only integers. In wallets, dApps, etc. this number is converted back to the actual balance with decimals.

To specify 2.5 tokens, for example, you would use 2.5 × 10<sup>18</sup> (= 2,500,000,000,000,000,000) instead. You can reverse it by multiplying with 10<sup>-18</sup> instead.

Comment: So, the supply is actually 10000, but its represented as 10,000 × 10^18 due to decimals, and the wallet apps make to divide the amount to display the correct supply of (10000).

Comment: Yes, that´s correct.